# Delete nodejs dirty db file

Tags: node.js, fs, node-dirty

I'm having problems deleting the db file create by NodeJS **Dirty** storage extension. As far as I can tell Dirty does not provide a method to delete the db file so I have to do this manually.

I've tried *fs.unlink()* and this executes properly but the file is not deleted until I terminate the node server which (I think) means that Dirty is still holding the file handle. The problem is that I cannot get the file handle from Dirty either because it uses *createReadStream* and *createWriteStream* methods which don't return file handles.

Is there any way I can delete the db file generated by Dirty, for example, when the client disconnects from the server?

Comment: Did you try to `delete db` first, to have it close the db file?

Comment: Yes actually I did but it still doesn't work. If I inspect the file after the unlink operation, it shows empty with a size of 0KB but it's still there. If I now close the node server, the file disappears, implying that the file handle is still open somewhere currently. The only feature that is accessing the db file is dirty

Answer (score 1):

Not to be annoying, but why are you trying to annoy it?  Maybe there's another way to deal w/ the problem.  Otherwise, the only help I could offer is perhaps forking Dirty and providing an option to kill the streams (http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options)

If you do end up going that route, please let me know and I'd be happy to help out-- I'm using DirtyDB for the in-memory database adapter for **[Sails](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails)** and **[Waterline](https://github.com/mikermcneil/waterline)**.